# Event Identifiers - ClientX and ClientY

Tags: javascript, events, identifier

I am trying to better understand the usage of the event attribute clientX and clientY.

I need to find the top and left offset of the mouse pointer when it moves over a particular div . The projectImage(x) function is attached to the onmouseover of the div. x is a function argument based on which the URL of a particular image can be determined.

Now. clientX is the left offset of the pointer at the time the mouseover event happens, so what can I enter for event in event.clientX

Th function below does not work (Reported as Not Defined by the JS Console) I think because of a syntax error in the first two lines.

```
function projectImage(x)
{

// Should the 1st two lines (right hand side) be x.clientY and x.clientX, 
// x is a function argument not event relevant to the pointer offset though

    var toffset = x.clientY ; // help_me_here.clientY

    var loffset = x.clientX ; // Event_Identifier_??.cleintX    

    var picdiv = document.getElementById("picdiv") ;
    picdiv.style.position = "absolute" ;
    picdiv.style.left = loffset + "px" ;
    picdiv.style.top = toffset + "px" ; 
    picdiv.innerHTML = "<img src='" + "http://imageServer.com/" + x.split("|")[1] + "' width='30px' />" ;

    picdiv.style.visibility = "visible";

}
```

Comment: How is `projectImage` called? What exactly is `x`?

Comment: <div onmouseover="projectImage('Joey|123');"> Joey </div> x is a string that is of the format "name|id" and imageserver.com/123 returns Joey's image

Comment: So `x` is a string... you should pass the event object instead or in addition.

Comment: @Felix King: Can you tell me how I should change the function ? I need the pointer offsets in variables toffset and loffset

Comment: x is a string and not something that can Identify the mouseover event when it occurred. If I want to grab the pointer offset in a variable, how should I do . I feel x is completely irrelevant in the first two lines and shouldn't be there at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FelixKling mentions you should be passing the event object.

I recommend switching to `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` instead of using inline events as well, I set you up an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nF6Kk/1/).

```
var x = document.getElementById('x');
var y = document.getElementById('y');
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    x.innerHTML = 'X: ' + e.clientX;
    y.innerHTML = 'Y: ' + e.clientY;
});​
```

If you're dead set on inline events, though, you can do it via `<div onmouseover="projectImage(event,'Joey|123');"> Joey </div>`

Comment: Hi Snuffle, This was most useful.. I have shifted to adding event listners. Once small problem is that the functions being attached to events are being called when the code for attaching functions with events is being parsed. Example:           document.getElementById("r" + id).addEventListener('mouseover', projectImage(event, friends[f].split("|")[0]), false) ;

Comment: Meanwhile I am going to be reading up the DOM documentation from scratch , the problem with self learned non professionals coders is that we don't start from the basics, we start from anywhere we can

Comment: @user1812787 Ah, that's because you're calling the function rather than passing a reference to it. If you wanted to do it without arguments you could just pass it `projectImage` (without the parenthesis) or you can declare a new anonymous function to pass it arguments. `function(e){projectImage(e, friends[f].split("|")[0]);}`  Event functions are automatically passed the event object, so the `e` in `function(e)` is just to pick that up.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is pass the event object to the function (and maybe refactor the arguments a bit):

```
<div onmouseover="projectImage(event || window.event, 'Joey', 123);"> Joey </div>
```

`event || window.event` is needed because IE is not passing the event object as argument to the event handler and thus has to be retrieved via `window`.

Also change your function to be able to access the those arguments:

```
function projectImage(event, name, id) {
    var toffset = event.clientY;
    var loffset = event.clientX;

    var picdiv = document.getElementById("picdiv") ;
    picdiv.style.position = "absolute" ;
    picdiv.style.left = loffset + "px" ;
    picdiv.style.top = toffset + "px" ; 
    picdiv.innerHTML = "<img src='http://imageServer.com/" + id + "' width='30px' />" ;

    picdiv.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Using meaningful variable names helps to understand the code easier.